# Can I hold iText5 and iText7 in the same maven project?

Tags: java, maven, itext

We have a maven project that uses iText5. We would like to migrate to iText7. There are many parts that use the old library. Are there any contraindications in temporarily keeping both libraries as a reference in the pom and using the old version in some parts and the new in others? We will gradually replace the old one. We will permanently delete the old one after a long process of refactoring and testing.

Comment: Depends on whether they use the same class and package names.

Comment: Also depends on dependency version conflicts.

Comment: There are no conflict on single functionality of sw.
I can replace all iText5 with iText7 for whole creation of single pdf.
It's a batch and there are creations of various pdf.
The sw, after a simple test works, I can create one of the pdf with iText7.
The others still use iText5. I ask my self if there is something I can't see... some intermediate contraindications in running mode in evidence (memory, space, etc...)
Is there some method to find any package conflicts? Anyway I don't use both in the same procedure, pdf productions are separated.

Answer (score 1):

when using itext5 and itext7 gives the same file errors.
need to exclude that file using the packaging option.
The below code will fix the compile-time build failed

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYGoThic-Medium.properties'
    }       
}
```

The below code will fix the Run-time build and make the application install

```
android {
        packagingOptions {
            
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/cjk_registry.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HeiseiKakuGo-W5.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HeiseiMin-W3.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYGoThic-Medium.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYSMyeongJo-Medium.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/HYSMyeongJoStd-Medium.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/KozMinPro-Regular.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MHei-Medium.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MSung-Light.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/MSungStd-Light.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/STSong-Light.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/STSongStd-Light.properties'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'
        }       
    }
```